# How to read and close a file in a one-liner?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use the following code to read a file in a list

```
list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(file)]
```

I have not closed the file manually, because I assume that Python does this with the garbage collector itself.

When I do testing (framework 'unittest') it warns me that the file is unclosed.

> ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test_resources/names.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>     return [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(file)]

How do I close the file in a one-liner?

Comment: Do you have a shortage of lines?

Comment: *"How do I close the file in a one-liner?"* You don't. You use a 2nd line of code.

Comment: The _cpython_ implementation of python closes the file with garbage collection. This should not be relied on though.

Comment: write a function if you want and then the functional call is one line

Comment: Use a `with open(...)` context manager and this handles the closing for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it like that, you won't ever be able to close that file, because `open(file)` is an unnamed variable that goes out of scope when the comprehension ends. As you found out yourself, the assumption "garbage collector closes the file once the comprehension is done" is not quite true: the GC is not running deterministically and you should not rely on it doing the cleanup for you.

The correct way to do this is via a `with` statement:

```
with open(file) as fp:
  list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in fp]
# file gets closed here in __exit__()
```

Comment: Not a one-liner though! 8-)

Comment: True enough, but (aside from removing the newline and calling it a one-liner) there is no way to close the file inside the comprehension. My point is, the file should have never been opened there in the first place.

Comment: AFAIK the garbage collector *does* close the file, but you never know when the garbage collector will actually run, and it's better to close the file explicitly as soon as you no longer need it. The context manager makes it more obvious that a file is being opened (which might throw an exception), too.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm not saying the GC won't close the file, I'm just saying relying on that is wrong (as the warning in the test clearly shows). I'll improve the wording to make that clearer ;)

Comment: you can do `from contextlib import closing` and then `closing([line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(file, 'r')]).thing`

Answer (score 2):

Strongly recommend `pathlib`, see more at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

```
from pathlib import Path
ss = Path('/path/to/file').read_text().splitlines()
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey Great! I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
Path(file).read_text().splitlines()
```

Using [`ilio`](https://pypi.org/project/ilio/):

```
contents = read('filename').splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading and closing a file in a single line:

```
with open('output.txt') as fd: list = [line.rstrip() for line in fd]
```

But there's no good reason to format your code that way.